# TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress JPA 2 with JpaRepository

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I want to use JPA with Spring data.

## pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.betlista</groupId>
    <artifactId>tests-jpa-spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
             <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId> 
             <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>c:\JavaLibs\hsqldb-2.2.9\hsqldb.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Apache Nexus</id>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
          <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
          <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

## applicationContext.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        ">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!--        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

    <bean
        scclass="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate"
        c:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"
        c:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

    <util:properties id="hibernateProperties">
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">32</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">32</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<!--        <property name="mappingResources"> -->
<!--            <list> -->
<!--            </list> -->
<!--        </property> -->
<!--        <property name="annotatedClasses"> -->
<!--            <util:list> -->
<!--            </util:list> -->
<!--        </property> -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver" />
<!--        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:src\main\resources\db\person" /> -->
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:c:/Betlista/WSs/Wicket/tests-jpa-spring/src/main/resources/db/person" />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```

## META-INF/persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="1.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd
        ">
    <persistence-unit name="JpaPersistenceUnit"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

## entity class

```java
package net.betlista.tests.jpa.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table( name = "PERSON" )
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private int age;

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId( final Long id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName( final String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setAge( final int age ) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

## service

```java
package net.betlista.tests.jpa.service;

import net.betlista.tests.jpa.entity.Person;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public interface IPersonService {

    List<Person> getAll();

    Person create( Person p );

}
```

implementation

```java
package net.betlista.tests.jpa.service;

import net.betlista.tests.jpa.dao.IPersonRepository;
import net.betlista.tests.jpa.entity.Person;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class PersonService implements IPersonService {

    @Autowired
    IPersonRepository personRepository;

    // @Autowired
    // EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Person> getAll() {
        return this.personRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Person create( final Person p ) {
        // final EntityTransaction transaction = this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().getTransaction();
        // transaction.begin();
        final Person savedPerson = this.personRepository.saveAndFlush( p );
        // transaction.commit();
        return savedPerson;

    }

}
```

## repository

```java
package net.betlista.tests.jpa.dao;

import net.betlista.tests.jpa.entity.Person;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface IPersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

}
```

## config

```java
package net.betlista.tests.jpa.dao;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan( "net.betlista.tests.jpa" )
@ImportResource( "classpath:applicationContext.xml" )
public class JavaConfig {

}
```

## and finally test

```java
package net.betlista.tests.jpa2;

import net.betlista.tests.jpa.dao.JavaConfig;
import net.betlista.tests.jpa.entity.Person;
import net.betlista.tests.jpa.service.IPersonService;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration( classes = { JavaConfig.class } )
public class PersonServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    IPersonService personService;

    @Test
    public void testGetAll() {
        final List<Person> allPersons = this.personService.getAll();
        Assert.assertNotNull( allPersons );
        System.out.println( "person count: " + allPersons.size() );
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreate() {
        final Person person = new Person();
        person.setName( "B" );
        person.setAge( 22 );
        this.personService.create( person );
    }

}
```

To verify the possibility it's HSQLDB problem I migrated to MySQL and I have same problem still. I just replaced `dataSource` configuration.

```xml
<bean>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/person" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="pass" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed my configuration completely. The test and the goal is the same. When I wrote I changed my configuration, that means `persistence.xml` and `applicationContext.xml` (service, entity and repository are the same).

## persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd
        ">

    <persistence-unit name="personPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

## applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    ">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="personPersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
                <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/avon" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Just had this problem, and while what I was missing was obvious, this answer helped me to pin-point it in sec. +1 and thanks a lot for taking the time to answer your own question.